# Create a default value when left join returns null

Tags: sql-server, left-join, isnull

I have a query like this

```
select * 
from Users u left join(
                       select ContactInformationId, 
                              Address, 
                              City, 
                              StateProvince, 
                              CountryId, 
                              ZipCode, 
                              PrimaryContactNumber, 
                              Fax, 
                              MobileNumber 
                       from ContactInformation
                     ) c on u.ContactInformationId = c.ContactInformationId 
left join  (
            select ISNULL(MerchantId, @MerchantId) as MerchantId, 
                   ISNULL(MerchantName, @MerchantName) as MerchantName, 
                   ISNULL(MerchantEmail, @MerchantEmail) as MerchantEmail, 
                   ISNULL(ContactInformationId, @ContactInformationId) as ContactInformationId 
            from Merchants
           ) m on c.ContactInformationId = m.ContactInformationId 
left join (
           select IsNull(MidId, 0) as MidId, 
                  IsNull(MidName, '') as MidName, 
                  IsNull(MerchantId, 0) as MerchantId, 
                  IsNull(Param_2, '') as Param_2, 
                  IsNull(Param_6, '') as Param_6 
           from Mids
          ) MID on m.MerchantId = MID.MerchantId 
where u.FirstName = '' and u.LastName = '' or u.MiddleName = ''
```

[image]

and the result like this. What I want to ask is, is there a way to make a default values for those NULL columns ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL()` in select query.

eg; I have set as 0 when MerchantId is null and set empty string when MidName is null

```
ISNULL(MerchantId, 0)
ISNULL(MidName, '')
```

Do this in the main query.

eg;

```
select ISNULL(m.MerchantId, 0), ISNULL(Mid.MidName, '') 
from Users u
```

Comment: Hi, I actually tried it but the result is the same as the image I posted. Any idea why ?

Comment: You need to do it in main query, not in sub queries.