# Join tables with corresponding row

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Table 1

```
Id | Name | CaseID
01 | ABC  |  114  
02 | ABC  |  114  
03 | ABC  |  115  
04 | ABC  |  115  
05 | ABC  |  116  
05 | ABC  |  116  
07 | ABC  |  116  
08 | ABC  |  117  
09 | ABC  |  118  
10 | ABC  |  119   
11 | ABC  |  120
```

Table2

```
T2Id | CaseID | CreatedDate
01   | 114    |  1 Mar 2023  
02   | 114    |  1 Mar 2023    
03   | 115    |  1 Mar 2023    
04   | 115    |  1 Mar 2023  
05   | 116    |  1 Mar 2023    
06   | 116    |  1 Mar 2023    
07   | 116    |  1 Mar 2023
```

I want a result something like this

```
Id | Name | CaseID | CreatedDate
01 | ABC  |  114   | 1 Mar 2023  
02 | ABC  |  114   | 1 Mar 2023  
03 | ABC  |  115   | 1 Mar 2023  
04 | ABC  |  115   | 1 Mar 2023  
05 | ABC  |  116   | 1 Mar 2023  
05 | ABC  |  116   | 1 Mar 2023  
07 | ABC  |  116   | 1 Mar 2023  
08 | ABC  |  117   | 1 Mar 2023  
09 | ABC  |  118   | 1 Mar 2023  
10 | ABC  |  119   | 1 Mar 2023  
11 | ABC  |  120   | 1 Mar 2023
```

I am using this

```
Select * from table1 t1
    left outer join table2 t2 on t1.caseID  = t2.caseID
```

I am getting 22 rows Please suggest some answers.

Comment: PLease dont spam tags!! Are you using SQLServer or MySQL, feel free to add back the relevant tag

Comment: I tried that as well still I am getting 22 records

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: BTW, you get 22 _rows_, not records.

Comment: Correct I am getting 22 rows the thing is still with distinct we will be table to pull the data from table1 only if we put table2 columns as well then again will 22 rows

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on two columns that both contain duplicate entries. In this case each duplicate from one table is matched with each one from the other table, e.g. for id 114 you get:

```
t1.id t1.caseid t2.id t2.caseid -- other columns ommitted
01    114       01    114
01    114       02    114
02    114       01    114
02    114       02    114
```

Analogously you get four entries for `115` and 9 for `116` while `117`, `118`, `119` and `120` produce yet another entry each with `NULL`s for the columns of table 2, so 4 + 4 + 9 + 4 = 21 entries in total (I suppose your test data has, in contrast to the data of the question, yet another row in table 1 without match in table 2 to get 22). Note that as there are different ids involved `DISTINCT` cannot help you out either unless you exclude the ids from the request (but the same problem then will arise again if you have differing values for `createddate`.

You can get the desired result (but with `CreatedDate` being `NULL` for entries `117`, `118`, `119` and `120`!) if you join on `id` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

This relies, though, on the ids of the entries in table 2 exactly matching the ids in table 1. Is this *always* the case? If not you need to add a column to table 2, possibly as foreign key, that matches the respective id from table 1, then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
```

Side note: On `NULL`s not being fine in the result you might possibly provide defaults for, see e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56840) for postgreSQL or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333090/create-a-default-value-when-left-join-returns-null) for MSSQL.

Answer (score -1):

The given query using an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.caseID = t2.caseID;
```

This will give you only the matching rows from both tables based on the caseID column, instead of all rows from table1 and only matching rows from table2 as in the original query.

Note that using SELECT * is generally not recommended in production code as it can lead to performance issues and unexpected results. It's better to explicitly specify the columns you need from each table.

Comment: Not using * in PROD but also with the Inner Join I am getting 17 rows still these are more as expected but I want only rows which are in table1 and pull there details from table2

Comment: Please try this.

    SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.CaseId as t1caseid, t2.*CaseId as t2caseid, t2.CreatedDate
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1caseid = t2caseid;